# Get data from a custom endpoint in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin with data that I get from a restAPI data source that I can customize for my needs, I've added a standard resource with only a `list` and an `edit` attributes:

```
<Resource name="topic" edit={TopicsEdit} list={TopicsList} />
```

When I look at the network tab of Chrome dev tools I see that I use the right endpoints:

For the list:

`GET` request for `http://api.loc/topic`

And for the edit:

`GET` request for `http://api.loc/topic/{{topic_id}}`

Up to this point everything works just fine.
My problem starts when I try to have the edit screen split into two tabs, one of them will be for editing the topic (This works just fine), and the other tab should use data from a different endpoint:

`http://api.loc/topic/{{topic_id}}/modifiers`

The code for my `TopicsEdit` file:

```
<Show {...props}>
    <TabbedShowLayout>
        <Tab label='topic'>
            <Edit {...props}>
                <SimpleForm>
                    <TextInput source="id"/>
                    <TextInput source="title"/>
                </SimpleForm>
            </Edit>
        </Tab>
        <Tab label='modifiers' path='modifiers'>
            <List {...props}>
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="id"/>
                    <TextField source="name"/>
                </Datagrid>
            </List>
        </Tab>
    </TabbedShowLayout>
</Show>
```

In the `topic` tab everything is working as I mentioned before, but when I switch to the `modifiers` tab I see in the network dev tool that the data arrives from

`http://api.loc/topic`

instead of

`http://api.loc/topic/{{topic_id}}/modifiers`

How can I customize the URL that the modifiers tab will pull the data from?

The only thing I did find was to use a `<ReferenceInput>` but the problem here is that the `reference=""` attribute will only get the info from a predefined structure, meaning that if I use `reference="modifiers"` it tries to fetch the data from:

`http://api.loc/modifiers`

And not from the desired URL.